# Strapi admin board 403: how to reset

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

My strapi admin board ( localhost:1337/admin ) turned into a bootloop due to 403:Forbidden error.

I haven't changed anything in my backend code, so i'm pretty sure that this isn't my fault. I've tried reinstalling strapi, then whole project, then reuploading the database schema again - still nothing.

Is there a way to handle this, or, at least, to restore default settings of strapi? I am using graphql, reactjs, strapi and mysql DB for this project.

Comment: Does this happen across different browsers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strapi API calling error: {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956118/strapi-api-calling-error-statuscode403-errorforbidden-messageforbi)