# gatsby-source-strapi returns 403 when nun public contentTypes are added

Tags: gatsby, strapi

In strapi I have configured 4 content-types, all ContentTypes have data

1. category
2. brand
3. product
4. order

Number 1 - 3 are all public and my application works fine when I do not include No. 4: order as a contentType in gatsby-config.js.
ContentType 4: order needs authentication, as I want only registered users to see their own orders.

*Working config settings*

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
  options: {
    apiURL: process.env.GATSBY_API_URL,        
    queryLimit: 5000, // Default to 100
    contentTypes: [`brand`, `category`, `product`],
  },
},
```

*Config settings that returns a:* **Request failed with status code 403**

```
  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL: process.env.GATSBY_API_URL,        
        queryLimit: 5000, // Default to 100
        contentTypes: [`brand`, `category`, `product`, `order`],
        // Possibility to login with a strapi user, when content types are not publically available (optional).
        loginData: {
           identifier: "Billi",
           password: "1234",
        },
      },
    },
```

Providing the login data or not brings the same result with the status code 403. When I remove the `order` from the ContentTypes the app builds as expected, without any errors.

Am I using the `loginData` incorrectly or is there more that needs to be done to include non public ContentTypes in this Gatsby Plugin?

Thank you for your help

Comment: having the exact same issue except i have 1 public request and the rest are authenticated returns the 403 until i remove the public request. Did you find an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strapi API calling error: {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956118/strapi-api-calling-error-statuscode403-errorforbidden-messageforbi)